# How to ensure a string is a number

Tags: c++

```
/* Checks if the inventory is valid. Criteria: Valid if and only if it contains only digits
*/
bool isValidInventory(string token) {
    char ch; // Will be used to store characters of a token so that they can be checked individually.
    for (int i = 0; i < token.length(); i++) {
        ch = token[i];

        if (isdigit(ch)) {
            return true;
        } else {
            return false;
        }
    }
} // End of isValidInventory() function.
```

This function essentially takes a token thats extracted from a string and validates if its a whole number. However, I'm facing an issue with the number `11.` and I'm not getting my desired result which is a message saying that the inventory is invalid since `11.` is not only digits.

I tried doing

```
if (isdigit(ch) && !ispunct(ch)) {}
```

But that did not work and obviously mod won't work here either as 11.0 % 1 = 0.

Comment: `return std::all_of(token.begin(), token.end(), [](unsigned char c)->bool { return isdigit(c); });`

Comment: What if the string is "1234567890123456789012345678901234567890"?  Is that a whole number?  How do you test for overflow?  You would be better off using [strtol](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/byte/strtol) and checking the returned `end` pointer instead of all of this code.  If the goal is to make sure the integer is one that's valid, it takes much more than to see if all characters are digits.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This should work if the string `token` is number like `11`, `110` or `2`.

```cpp
bool isValidInventory(string token) {
    for (auto ch: token) 
        if (isdigit(ch) == false) return false;
    return true;
}
```

In case, the number is formatted like this `11.00`. You may need to check for this `.` specific character.

```cpp
bool isValidInventory(const string& token, int dotCount = 0) {
    for (auto ch: token) {
        if (ch == '.') { if (++dotCount > 1) return false; }
        else if (isdigit(ch) == false) return false;
    }
    return token.size();  // for this logic thanks to Remy Lebeau 
}
```

Comment: Is `1....2` a valid number?

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out. Updated.

Answer (score 8):

You return true or false on the first iteration of the loop.

It is impossible for your code to ever even look at the second character of the string.

Answer (score 4):

Your function has 3 problems:

- it always `return`s a value on the 1st iteration regardless of whatever `isdigit()` returns. So, you are not checking the whole `token`.
- if `token` is empty, the function exhibits *undefined behavior*, as it doesn't `return` any value at all.
- you need to cast the `char` to `unsigned char` before passing it to `isdigit()`.

Try this:

```
bool isValidInventory(const string &token) {
    if (token.empty()) {
        return false;
    }
    unsigned char ch;
    for (size_t i = 0; i < token.length(); ++i) {
        ch = static_cast<unsigned char>(token[i]);
        if (!isdigit(ch)) {
            return false;
        }
    }
    return true;
}
```